# How to initialize or change a dataframe according to my index length?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an index that looks like:

```
MyIndex
11
12
13
```

and a dataframe which might be longer than my index: (they could be equal under some situations)

```
OldIndex c1
0        00
1        01
2        02
3        03
4        04
```

I want to fit the dataframe into the index (by dropping the extra rows at the tail)
.

```
MyIndex c1
11      00
12      01
13      02
```

Is there any simple solution? It would be better if I can achieve this without creating a new dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
my_idx = pd.Series([11, 12, 13], name='MyIndex')
df = pd.DataFrame({'OldIndex': [0,1,2,3,4], 
                'c1':['00', '01', '02', '03', '04']}).set_index('OldIndex')
l = len(my_idx)

df = df.iloc[:l].set_index(idx.index)

         c1
MyIndex    
11       00
12       01
13       02
```

Answer (score 0):

simple way to do it would just be this...

assuming you have:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=[0,1,2])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'c1':[1,2,3,4,5]},index=[0,1,2,3,4])
df1['c1'] = df2['c1'].values[:len(df1.index)]
```

output:

```
>>> df1
   c1
0   1
1   2
2   3
```

without creating a new df...

say ind = `pd.Index([0,1,2])`

```
df2, df2.index = df2.iloc[:len(ind)], ind
```

output:

```
>>> df2
   c1
0   1
1   2
2   3
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the desired index (as `pd.Index`) and then set this index to the new df (subset based on the length of the new index)

```
myindex = pd.Index(['I1','I2','I3'])
df = df.iloc[:len(myindex)].set_index(myindex)
```

Output:

```
    c1
I1  00
I2  01
I3  02
```